# Parsing words divided by commas or spaces in a text file- Can I overcome the commas with scanf?

Tags: c, parsing, char

I have a text file which contains lines, such that every line contains no more than 80 chars. every line contains (one or more words) divided by **commas or spaces**. I need lexicography sort the words. I want to use **scanf** with the symbol "%s" of strings, but it considers only spaces. So I guess I can't. any smarter way to deal with the parsing the words than  get char by char?

Here's a sketch of what I was planning to do:

```
   char**arr;
    arr=calloc(Size, sizeof(char)*80);
    int m=0;

    while (!feof(file)) {

        char c=fgetc(file);
        while (c!='/n') {
             j=0;
            char* current;
            current=calloc(1,sizeof(char)*80);
            while (c!=','&& c!=' ' && c!='/n') {
                current[j]=c;
                j++;
                c=fgetc(c);
            }
            current[j]='\0';
            arr[m]=current;

            free(current);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know about the [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) function?  I think you might find it helpful.

Comment: can I use it with "/n" as well? 
pch = strtok (str," , /n  ")?

Comment: You have a problem with `'/n'`, it's not a single character but two. I think you mean `'\n'`?

Comment: Yep - but follow Joachim's advice and change it to a backslash (assuming you want to break on newlines).  Cheers!

Comment: You also have a problem with that you are allocating memory, and then freeing that memory, all the while you save a pointer to that memory. After you call `free` you should not access that memory.

Comment: Does strtok puts '\0' at the ends of each string it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an entire line in a suitable variable (`line`, below), you could use something like:

```
const char *ptr = line;
char token[80];

while(*ptr != '\0' && sscanf(ptr, "%79[^, ]", token) == 1)
{
  ptr += strlen(token);
  while(*ptr == ',' || *ptr == ' ')
    ++ptr;
}
```

This uses the (rather under-utilized, in my opinion) character group format `%[]` to grab characters until a comma or space is found, then skip past the parsed token, and any separators that follow.